# Trying to add an id to a circle

Tags: d3.js

I am doing research for a professor at my school and I am coding in d3. I am creating a graph that has tool tips and you can toggle the graph by clicking on the legend. However, when I toggle the lines disappears but I can't get the tool tips associated to that line.  I know I need to somehow add an id to these circles but I have no idea how. I have included my code below to show what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
stroke: white;
stroke-width: 2;
fill: none;
}

 .axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: grey;
stroke-width: 1;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

div.tooltip {   
position: absolute;         
text-align: center;         
width: 170px;                   
height: 500px;                  
padding: 1px;               
font: 12px sans-serif;      
background: lightsteelblue; 
border: 0px;        
border-radius: 5px;         
pointer-events: none;           
 }
.legend {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
text-anchor: middle;
}

</style>
<body>

 <!-- load the d3.js library -->    
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

 <script>

 // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 150, bottom: 60, left: 80},
    width = 1160 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;  

// Parse the date / time


// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width-100]);
var formatxAxis=d3.format('.0f');
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

 // Define the axe
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x)
.tickFormat(formatxAxis).ticks(20);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y)
.ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
.curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
.x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.count); });


// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
.attr("class", "tooltip")               
.style("opacity", 0);

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.json("satisfaction.json", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.year  = +d.year;
    d.count = +d.count;
  });
 // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);

//nest the entries by symbol
var dataNest = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) {
    return d.word;
})
.entries(data); 



//define colors for the lines 
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

// spacing for the legend
 legendSpace = width/dataNest.length; 

 var circleid = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataNest)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", function(d){
    return "circle" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  });   

   // Loop through each symbol / key
   dataNest.forEach(function(d,i) { 

    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
            return d.color = color(d.key); })
        .attr("id", 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '')) // assign ID
        .attr("d", valueline(d.values));


    // Add the Legend
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", width - margin.left + 50)
        .attr("y", legendSpace/4 + i*(legendSpace/6))
        .attr("class", "legend")    // style the legend
        .style("fill", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
            return d.color = color(d.key); })
        .on("click", function(){
            // Determine if current line is visible 
            var active   = d.active ? false : true,
            newOpacity = active ? 0 : 1; 
            // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
            d3.select("#tag"+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
                .transition().duration(100) 
                .style("opacity", newOpacity); 
            // Update whether or not the elements are active
            d.active = active;
                // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
            d3.select("circle" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''))
                .transition().duration(100) 
                .style("opacity", newOpacity); 
            })              
        .text(d.key); 

   });


   // Add the scatterplot
    svg.selectAll("dot")    
    .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)       
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.year); })       
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.count); })     
    .on("click", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);      
        div .html(d.word + "<br/>" + d.count + "<br/>"  + d.songs)  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 25) + "px");    
        })                  
      .on("dblclick", function(d) {     
        div.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0);   
      })
;  
   // Add the X Axis
   svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

   // Add the Y Axis
   svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

   });

   </script>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are trying to set your `id` before you have added the circles to the graph. Instead, you can set the `id` when you're appending the circles to your graph.

```
// Add the scatterplot
    svg.selectAll("dot")    
    .data(data)         
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("id", function(d){ return "circle" + d.key.replace(/\s+/g, ''); })          
     // ^---- add the id here when you're appending the circles 
    .attr("r", 5)       
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.year); })       
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.count); })     
    .on("click", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
            .duration(200)      
            .style("opacity", .9);      
        div .html(d.word + "<br/>" + d.count + "<br/>"  + d.songs)  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 25) + "px");    
        })                  
      .on("dblclick", function(d) {     
        div.transition()        
            .duration(500)      
            .style("opacity", 0);   
      })
;
```

Comment: Hey! So I took your advice but my code is still not working for some reason. Do you know what else could be the issue?